# java : collection <Object[]> : listfiles

Tags: java

I would like to set a collection of object using listfiles instead of doing this manually :

```
@Paramaters
public static Collection<Object[]> data()
{
     Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{"test_files/myfilea.txt"}, {"test_files/myfileb.txt"},{"test_files/myfilec.txt"},{"test_files/myfiled.txt"}};

return Arrays.asList(data);
}
```

Any idea, solution, please.

Comment: why `Object` why not `File` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear... what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: i need to parse all the files in the folder 'test_files'. i start my fonction by setting my data with this code. it works perfectly fine with object, so i don't really want to change it into a list.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
File theDirectory = new File("test_files");
File[] theFiles;
if(theDirectory.isDirectory()) 
    theFiles = theDirectory.listFiles();
else
    return null; //Or throw exception... up to you
List<Object[]> yourFilesList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();   //Edited here
for(File f: theFiles)
{
    if(f.isFile())
        //yourFilesList.add(new Object[]{f.getName()});       //Edited here again
        // or your code may rely on directory also so you can do this
         yourFilesList.add(new Object[]{"test_files/" + f.getName()}); 
}
return yourFilesList;
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work either. i get the same error : data() must return an Iterable of arrays. i need a collection of objets ... I think

Comment: Oh its because you are expecting a Collection of Object Arrays, Files are Objects.

Comment: @user2762275 See my edits to make this work, just change Lists to Object Arrays by adding `[]`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch but when i debug it found the write number of files in my folder

Comment: This sounds like a problem generated in a different part of the code as this list is a list of Files not Strings like your original code, you should update your other code, or look at my edits again

Comment: all most !!! just the path of the folder is missing. i get myfilea.txt instead of test_files/myfilea.txt

Comment: @user2762275 To get what you say, use the (previously commented out) line instead of the line I left in (now commented out), I'll edit it again

Comment: So, the problem was OP wanted a collection of an array of arrays each of a string, and there we were trying collections of files and collections of arrays of an array of strings and **good grief**...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? If not please clarify.

```
public static Collection<File> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new File("test_files").listFiles());
}
```

If you must have the array within a collection, try this:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return java.util.Collections.singleton((Object[])new File("test_files").listFiles());
}
```

Edit: One more try:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    String[] fileNames = new File("test_files").list();
    Object[] namesInObjectArray = new Object[fileNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        namesInObjectArray[i] = "test_files/" + fileNames[i];
    }
    Object[][] outerObjectArray = new Object[][] { namesInObjectArray };
    return Arrays.asList(outerObjectArray);
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work i get : data() must return an Iterable of arrays. thanks anyway

Comment: i got the message : "The method singleton(Object)[]) is undefined for the type PolicyUtils.Collections". sorry i am really new to java

Comment: @user2762275 Ah, I meant [`java.util.Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Since you already have another class called Collections, putting `java.util.` in front of the name will tell the compiler which one is wanted.

Comment: @user2762275 Where...?

Comment: sorry ... at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance

Comment: @user2762275 That's sounds like a different problem in a different part of code.

Comment: i am not sure cause i have exactly the same files than the list above

Comment: @user2762275 Sorry, I missed the fact that you were returning bare file path strings instead of `File` objects. See if my last edit helps. Otherwise I give up.

Comment: I missed that also, seems like a bizarre way to code this but hard to tell what OPs requirements are. +1 for your original oneliners tho.

Comment: weird ... same error again. i think it's for data() who is org.junit.runners.parameterized.parameters with [at]target and [at]retention